# Как проверить находится ли телефон, на котором установлено приложение, в сети?

Tags: java, android, сеть

Как проверить находится ли телефон, на котором установлено приложение, в сети?

Сейчас проверяю так: отправляю смс, если смс отправляется то ок, а если статус `SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE` то нет.

Нужен способ без отправки смс.

Comment: А, что Вам даст такая проверка? Ну проверили Вы, телефон оказался в сети. Только собрались делать звонок, а человек зашел в метро и сеть пропала. Правильнее - совершать необходимые действия и анализировать возвращаемые ошибки

Comment: @AntonShchyrov , поправил (обновил) вопрос

Comment: Довольно дорогая проверка выходит. :) Ну и Антон выше правильно пишет, проверять доступность ресурса лучше в момент выполнения действия, а не заранее.